# unable to ping other machine via two routers, 1 network

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp, ipconfig

I managed to setup  2 routers with different isp providers to be joined in 1 local network. Router1 is dhcp enabled and Router2 is disabled dhcp, set static ip from Router1's ip range.

I connected 2 laptops to different routers. Laptop1 is connected via wifi to Router1. Then I performed a ping request to check Router2 and Laptop2 and successfully responded.

My issue here is Laptop2 connected to Router2 via lan cable (set static ip using Router2 as gateway and still under ip range of Router1). I can connect to the internet but i cannot ping to Router1 and Laptop1.

- What seems to be the problem?
- Should I configure something in Router2?
- Is there a tool to help me configure this kind of setup?

Comment: How is Router1 connected to Router2?

Comment: They are connected via lan cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out the solution for this. Now sharing it to others with the same scenario. Here's what i did :

- Set Router1 DHCP to a specific range  (192.168.100.100 to 200). Router1's IP is 192.168.100.254
- Reserve static IP of 192.168.100.200 for Router2 (via MAC address)
- Set Router2's IP to 192.168.100.200
- Enable Router2's DHCP with specific range (192.168.100.201 to 230)
- Connect Router1 and Router2 via LAN port/cable

Now they are connected locally but different internet subscription.
Tested connection via Quickbooks multi-user connection.

If you have something to add or raise issue on my solution, feel free to post.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently trying to create a load-balancing network using
two ISPs, but Router2 is not correctly set to route local IPs to
Router1. You can already see that by the fact that you needed to
set Laptop2 to static IP for this to partially work, as it couldn't
access Router1 for its DHCP.

If you can in Router2 add routes, you could specify that local IPs should
go to Router1 as gateway, leaving all other routes to go to ISP2.

Another possibility is if Laptop2 has a WiFi adapter, for it to also
connect to Router1 directly. The routing will then be automatic,
without the need for a static IP on the WiFi adapter or for a
direct connection between the two routers.

Just to note that load-balancing should best be done by using a
[load-balancing router](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=load-balancing+router),
also called Dual Wan or Multi Wan, that can connect directly to both ISPs.
This would have the advantage of automatically distributing all
the connections without you manually needing to specify any routes.

Comment: The scenario is different sir.Machine connecting to Router1 is subscribe to a dedicated public ip.Issue with Router1 is the isp having limited bandwidth. Looking for a solution for having Router2 (mobile internet) with a larger bandwidth capacity for client unit consumption but needs access to Router1's local ip to access other machines.Cannot transfer to other isp due to lock-in issue of the provider in the operation area.

Comment: Perhaps if you added to your post a schema of your network with all these points marked-in.

Comment: I'm prototyping the current network setup of the office. I can't explore it directly to avoid messing up the operation. I found this link which i though will work also in our office (https://superuser.com/questions/635515/two-internet-connections-two-routers-one-network).

Comment: I think that your case is different from that post.